# Understanding PyTorch implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

So I came across this code:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
loss_cls = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target)
```

I wanted to see more about the binary_cross_entropy_with_logits function which is a sum of logs, so I head over to the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits) which leads me to the source code [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#binary_cross_entropy_with_logits)

All this does is `return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)`

I want to see the actual code where the sum of logs is being performed. Where can I see the source code for torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits

Comment: The functional code is mostly written in C++. The C++ source code is not delivered with the python package but can be explored on github. For example [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Loss.cpp#L202) is the entry point for the `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` function.